# Create Docker image to run web application in tomcat but without os

Tags: docker

I want to create a new Docker image to run our Java based web application in Tomcat.
But till now what I found is that most of the default images comes with inbuild OS (e.g. Ubuntu/Debian etc...). 
So here are my question:
1. Can we create an image which will have JRE and Tomcat with our app and no OS?
Because, if I run this image in VM, then VM will have its own OS and again in container there is another OS.
So that's the use of having containers with OS?

Comment: Image is automatically based on OS, cause a container can't run without OS. If you want to deploy a tomcat without OS you can't use docker, in my opinion.
You have to ask you why you use docker

Comment: Why would you run a Docker image *inside another virtual machine*…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker images for Ubuntu, Debian ... are not operating systems. They don't have a linux kernel. They are just images having file structure and tools similar to an Ubuntu, Debian OS distribution.

The container does not have it own kernel, it uses the host's kernel where the container is running. This is the fundamental differnece between a virtual machine and a container.